# FourSquare Client library for WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, foursquare

Is there any foursquare client library available for Windows Phone 8. i checked the foursquare site and this client 'Sharp Square' but whenever i try to include it in my project i got the version incompatible error

```
install-package : Could not install package 'SharpSquare 1.0.0.2'. You are trying to
install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0',
but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are
compatible with that framework.
```

i also tried adding the .dll after building the [project](https://github.com/TICLAB/SharpSquare) but got the same error..

Comment: did you try searching in nuget?

Comment: i tried installing from nugget "SharpSquare 1.0.0.2" but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loking at the source code of SharpSquare on GitHub (https://github.com/TICLAB/SharpSquare) there is no version that works with Windows Phone 8.

You need to convert it to a Windows Phone library. It should not be difficult, just removing the unnecessary references to System.Web and making all the request asynchronous. Here is my take on it, it compiles but I have not tested it: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73642/SharpSquareWP8.zip

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you can do is leverage Foursquare REST API https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/

And a library like RestSharp to work with them.